# How do I take information from one function to use in another in python without using return?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

```
def ind():
    galos = eval(input("What was the starting integer??\n"))
    galoe = eval(input("What was the ending integer?\n"))
    use = galoe - galos
    round(use,1)
    if (use < 4000000):
        fin = 1000
    elif (use > 4000000) and (use < 10000000):
        fin = 2000.00
    else:
        use1 = use - 10000000
        start = 2000.00
        fin = str(start + (0.00025 * use))
        print ("Your bill is:$" + fin)

def bill(code):
    print("Code:" + code)
    print("Beggining reading:" + galos)
    print("Ending reading:" + galoe)
    print("Gallons used:" + use)
    print("Money owed:$" + fin)
```

I am writing a basic code that creates a "water bill." I am trying to use `galos` in `bill()`, but I keep getting this error:

> NameError: name 'galos' is not defined

How can I get that information?

Answer (score 0):

Use globals (I dont recommend that)

```
# Start script
globals galos, galoe, use, fin


def ind():
    globals galos, galoe, use, fin
    galos = eval(input("What was the starting integer??\n"))
    ...
```

I recommend you too look at Classes

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons to write a function. One is to carry out some action (example `print()`) and the other is to calculate values and return them.

You say that you don't want to use `return` but in a function that does calculations not wanting to use `return` does not make a lot of sense.

At the end of your function `ind()`, add

```
return code, galos, galoe, use, fin
```

Call `ind()` like this:

```
code, galos, galoe, use, fin = ind()
```

and use these returned values in your `print()` calls.

You *can* use global variables for this, and that will work in a toy program, but there are good reasons not to unless there is no alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple class as a container for your data:

```
class Bill:

    def __init__(self, code):
        self.code = code
        self.galos = eval(input("What was the starting integer??\n"))
        self.galoe = eval(input("What was the ending integer?\n"))

        self.use = self.galoe - self.galos

        self.use = round(self.use, 1)

        if (self.use < 4000000):
            self.fin = 1000
        elif (self.use > 4000000) and (self.use < 10000000):
            self.fin = 2000.00
        else:
            use1 = self.use - 10000000  # not used?
            start = 2000.00
            self.fin = str(start + (0.00025 * self.use))
            print ("Your bill is:$" + self.fin)

        self.bill()  # this will call the class method 'bill' 
                     # defined below and generate the output

    def bill(self):
        print("Code:", self.code)
        print("Beggining reading:", self.galos)
        print("Ending reading:", self.galoe)
        print("Gallons used:", self.use)
        print("Money owed:$", self.fin)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bill = Bill(5234)
```

Running this will output this:

```
What was the starting integer??
123
What was the ending integer?
1235
Code: 5234
Beggining reading: 123
Ending reading: 1235
Gallons used: 1112
Money owed:$ 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have stated above, global variables are your golden ticket here.
Here is one way that you can implement these:

```
def ind():
    global galos, galoe, use, fin
    galos = eval(input("What was the starting integer??\n"))
    galoe = eval(input("What was the ending integer?\n"))
    use = galoe - galos
    round(use,1)
    if (use < 4000000):
        fin = 1000
    elif (use > 4000000) and (use < 10000000):
        fin = 2000.00
    else:
        use1 = use - 10000000
        start = 2000.00
        fin = str(start + (0.00025 * use))
        print ("Your bill is:$" + fin)


def bill(code):
    # Use string formatting throughout print statements here,
    # string concatenation ("abc" + var) expects a string type.
    print("Code:%i" %code)
    print("Beggining reading:%i" %galos)
    print("Ending reading:%i" %galoe)
    print("Gallons used:%i" %use)
    print("Money owed:$%.2f" %fin)

galos = 0
galoe = 0
use = 0
fin = 0

ind()
bill(1234)
```

Also notice the difference in print statements above, this is called string formatting and is another tool I would recommend adding to your kit.